# Adding collection of objects to another collection

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm fairly new to c# and .NET MVC, so sorry for not knowing the correct vocabulary.

I have an API that I call from a native Android application.

I'm sending a GET request to get a number of 'propositions' (code is in dutch, school said to do so, I know otherwise...).

So far so good, here's my repository function:

```
 public IEnumerable<BegrotingsVoorstel> getVoorstelVanProject(int id)
        {
            return ctx.BegrotingsVoorstellen.Where(b => b.ProjectId == id).AsEnumerable();
        }
```

I get this JSON back:

```
{
    "begrotingsVoorstelId": 1,
    "titel": "Algemeen bespaard",
    "beschrijving": "Voor mij mag er vooral bij algemene financiering bespaard worden.",
    "gebruikerId": 4,
    "projectId": 1
  }
```

But now I want to add a collection (or list or whatever) of media links (photo's) into a collection field in the objects I'm giving back.

I'm expecting this kind of JSON:

```
{
    "begrotingsVoorstelId": 1,
    "titel": "Algemeen bespaard",
    "beschrijving": "Voor mij mag er vooral bij algemene financiering bespaard worden.",
    "gebruikerId": 4,
    "projectId": 1,
    "begrotingsVoorstelMedia": [{
        "begrotingsVoorstelMediaId": 1,
        "url": "/images/test.jpeg"
      }]
  }
```

Now here's the tricky part, begrotingsVoorstelMedia is currently empty, no idea how to get it inside, Visual Studio keeps throwing various errors at me..

For now, this is my repository function, it doesn't give any errors, but also no data...

```
public IEnumerable<BegrotingsVoorstel> getVoorstelVanProject(int id)
{
    IEnumerable<BegrotingsVoorstel> help = new List<BegrotingsVoorstel>();
    help = ctx.BegrotingsVoorstellen.Where(b => b.ProjectId == id).AsEnumerable();
    foreach(BegrotingsVoorstel voorstel in help)
    {
        voorstel.BegrotingsVoorstelMedia.Concat(ctx.BegrotingsVoorstelMedias.Where(c => c.BegrotingsVoorstelId == voorstel.BegrotingsVoorstelId));
    }
    return help;
}
```

For extra information, here's my "BegrotingsVoorstelMedia" Model and BPContext file:

```
public class BegrotingsVoorstelMedia
{
    [Key]
    public int BegrotingsVoorstelMediaId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public int BegrotingsVoorstelId { get; set; }
    public virtual BegrotingsVoorstel BegrotingsVoorstel { get; set; }
}
```

BPCONTEXT=

```
 public DbSet<BegrotingsVoorstelMedia> BegrotingsVoorstelMedias { get; set; }
```

thanks in advance!

**UPDATED REPOSITORY FUNCTION**

```
public IEnumerable<BegrotingsVoorstel> getVoorstelVanProject(int id)
{
    IEnumerable<BegrotingsVoorstel> help = new List<BegrotingsVoorstel>();
    List<BegrotingsVoorstelMedia> help2 = new List<BegrotingsVoorstelMedia>();
    help = ctx.BegrotingsVoorstellen.Where(b => b.ProjectId == id).AsEnumerable();
    foreach(BegrotingsVoorstel voorstel in help)
    {
        help2.Clear();
        help2 = ctx.BegrotingsVoorstelMedias.Where(c => c.BegrotingsVoorstelId == voorstel.BegrotingsVoorstelId).ToList();
        foreach(BegrotingsVoorstelMedia voorstelMedia in help2)
        {
            voorstel.BegrotingsVoorstelMedia.Add(voorstelMedia);
        }
    }
    return help;
}
```

Comment: Why `Concat`and not `AddRange` in `voorstel.BegrotingsVoorstelMedia.Concat(ctx.BegrotingsVoorstelMedias.Where(c => c.BegrotingsVoorstelId == voorstel.BegrotingsVoorstelId));`?

Comment: AddRange doesn't exist in ICollection ? I can add .Add, but then the error is "cannot convert from ...IQueryable to Dal.Domain.Media.BegrotingsVoorstelMedia" but I know I need to add .AsEnumerable() to fix this, but then the error is "cannot convert from IEnumerable to Dal.Domain.Media.BegrotingsVoorstelMedia"

Comment: I realise that I need to convert the query to ICollection, but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. Stick to LINQ and do it like this:

```
public IEnumerable<BegrotingsVoorstel> getVoorstelVanProject(int id)
{
    var help = ctx.BegrotingsVoorstellen.Where(b => b.ProjectId == id);

    foreach(BegrotingsVoorstel voorstel in help)
    {
        var medias = ctx.BegrotingsVoorstelMedias
            .Where(c => c.BegrotingsVoorstelId == voorstel.BegrotingsVoorstelId).ToList(); 
        voorstel.BegrotingsVoorstelMedia = voorstel.BegrotingsVoorstelMedia.Concat(medias);
    }

    return help;
}
```

Keep in mind that the LINQ extension methods DON'T work against the collection they're invoked on. Instead they return new IEnumerable as appropriate. Another important aspect of LINQ extension methods is that they're implementing "deffered execution", meaning you need to materialize the result when needed by iterating over the collection or use `ToList()`, `ToArray()`, etc.

If you want to go without LINQ, you need to call `AddRange()` after `medias` initialization, like so:

```
voorstel.BegrotingsVoorstelMedia.AddRange(medias);
```

Comment: Your answer makes sense, my code doesn't, I'm getting a self referencing loop, could it be that the problem is caused by the 'virtual' variable in BegrotingsVoorstelMedia? I've read something about this and I'm using DTO models to filter my objects before I pass them, however this does not happen in the repository yet

Comment: So I commented out the virtual parameter in the model shown above. I've also deleted the code in BPContext that made the EF relation, now it's working great. However I did not write the Entity Framework myself so I have no clue for why the 'virtual' parameter should be there because there is an ID of the parent table... Anywayz, going to accept this as answer, since it's the most explained. Thank you for your time! (ps, if you got some extra usefull info about why the virtual parameter is there, you'll be my hero)

Answer (score 2):

You need to call "AddRange" and convert the query to List (also make sure your collection is newed up in BegrotingsVoorstel's ctor. I don't recall but AddRange may not exist in ICollection, so you just do another loop inside each foreach statement.

```
voorstel.BegrotingsVoorstelMedia.AddRange(ctx.BegrotingsVoorstelMedias.Where(c => c.BegrotingsVoorstelId == voorstel.BegrotingsVoorstelId).ToList());
```

Comment: I see what the problem is, but still some weird errors.. 

"Self referencing loop detected for property 'BegrotingsVoorstel'

See updated repository function in question, Thanks